# Setting up Subsonic 3.0 on a ASP.NET web application on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, templates, subsonic3

I followed the steps on this tutorial [video](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo) by at subsonic website. Everything seems to be self explanatory but when I copy the .tt files into my Visual Studio nothing  happens.

I have read other question relating to this problem on this website but they don't seem to fix this problem. I also went into the regedit to find out the generator key for .tt files and it is properly set.

This is not a visual studio express or anything but a professional edition also I am trying to build a ASP.net web application and not a MVC application like the demo.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Added the subsonic3 tag for ya. Might get Rob's attention that way, who knows.

Comment: I tried using a console and mvc application and it worked fine. Does that mean Subsonic cannot be used with ASP.Net Web application I know that doesnt makes sense. My company has not been swtitching to 3.5 for some reason and thats why I lost of the train and right now totally clueless. In asp.net 2.0 web app I used to define subsonic section is web.config and add a build.abp inside the App_Code and everytime I needed subsonic to regenrate the dal, I used to modify it and it used to create the DAL neatly under a namespce. I guess subsonic 3.0 doesnt support this way of doing it. Help Please!!!